# Java: instantiate an abstract class with a "wrong" argument

Tags: java, class, oop, initialization, abstract

Say I have this unmodifiable class:

```
public abstract class MyClass {
    int value;
    /** @version 1.0 */
    MyClass(int value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

This is a code for "version 1.0" of a program. "version 1.1" has this:

```
public abstract class MyClass {
    String value;
    /** @version 1.1 */
    MyClass(String value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

I need to initialize the 1.1 constructor while working with 1.0 API. For example:

```
/** initializing on version 1.0 */
MyClass clazz = new MyClass("str");
```

Obviously doesn't work, because the 1.0 API expects an int. Another problem is that the class is abstract. I also cannot use the 1.1 API for a very specific thing related to my application. So, what is the way to initialize an abstract class with an unexpected argument? Reflection drops InstantiationException.

Comment: Why do you think you can instantiate an abstract class?

Comment: Because I can directly = new MyClass(100). And I need to do it with an unexpected argument,

Comment: You can't.  What you have there is literally a syntax error that the compiler won't let you compile.  Better tell us what's really going on, your question makes no sense.

Comment: @LeopardLGD you certainly can't do `new MyClass(100)` since `MyClass` is `abstract`. Please check that assumption.

Comment: The only way `new MyClass(100)` works if you specific a class body right after that statement, creating an anonymous subclass.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I was writing this fast. I meant new MyClass(100) { // methods }

Comment: OK, now that we have syntax issues squared away, see Stephen's answer below.  You can't.

Comment: You should also learn about [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) as an important concept in software maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to create an instance of a class (abstract or otherwise) passing it an argument that doesn't match the constructor's declared signature.

If you want version 1.1 to be compatible with 1.0, you need to have both of the 1.0 and 1.1 constructors.  For example, you could code it like this:

```
public abstract class MyClass {
    String value;

    /** @version 1.1 */
    MyClass(String value) { this.value = value; }

    /** @version 1.0 */
    MyClass(int value) { this.value = Integer.toString(value); }
}
```

Comment: I can't modify the API.

Comment: Then you are screwed.  There is no way to pass a constructor argument of the wrong type.